# Should use BY or PER in a marketing communication?

Tags: marketing

Situation: any time a task is concluded, the executor receives money, and the client receives a product.

For marketing purposes, what would be the best way to communicate it for the executor and the client at the same time, between the next two options?

- Get BY Task
- Get PER Task

Comment: No idea.  None of your text makes sense.  I can't tell what you're talking about at all.

Answer (score 1):

Per. It means "for each". The word "By" is not as clear.